# Galera, MariaDB and multiple datacenter

Tags: mariadb, galera

Looking into using Galera and MariaDB across 3 data centers. We have a metroE comnection between the sites. Connectivity is pretty stable, but my concern is if a WAN link goes down at one of the sites, and I am writing to the local nodes.

How does it handle that situation?

How many nodes at minimum at each site is recommended?

This question was similar, but different:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777134/galera-cluster-replication-between-two-data-centers/27793927#27793927

Answer (score 1):

If the WAN link breaks, the cluster will split into 2 clusters. The bigger cluster will be a `PRIMARY` cluster, meaning that it will work properly. The other partition won't accept any write until it re-joins with the `PRIMARY` cluster and the data in the nodes are updated.

Note that it is very important to set a good value for `evs.suspect_timeout`. Before this timeout occurs, the whole cluster will wait a response from unreachable node. After that timeout occurs, the cluster is partitioned. If the value is too low, slow nodes may cause a cluster partitioning. If the timeout is too high, working nodes may wait uselessly for a response from unreachable nodes.

Comment: How does the smaller cluster know it is the smaller cluster?

Comment: If cluster_size > all_nodes / 2, it is a PRIMARY cluster. If not, it isn't. That's the reason why you should never have a 2 nodes cluster: if one crashes, the other one cannot be PRIMARY.